# Binning Logistic Regression Results by Output in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, binning

I have a logistic regression in R whose goal is to predict the probability of default on some test data.

`glm(default ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X1:term + term:X5 - 1, family="binomial", data=mydata)`

What I'd like to do is 'bin' this data so that bins 1 to n each have a certain rate of default. How can I bin the logistic regression results in this way? For example, the bins on a sample set of 1000 might look like:

```
Bin# P(Default) Count
1         4%     400
2         2%     300
3         1%     300
```

That is, I set in advance the probabilities I want each bin to have (.04,.02,.01) and then bins are created based around those settings.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you are using to bin your data.  Are you just trying to bin by certain predicted probabilities in order of increasing predicted probability?

Comment: @StatsStudent Good point, I've updated my question. The goal is to create bins based on probabilities picked in advance.

Comment: Why lose information through binning?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you are trying to do, but I'm not sure this is possible. What if none of your predicted probabilities are anywhere near .04?  What if they are all in the .80s?

Comment: @StatsStudent You may be right, there is information that needs to be known beforehand to ensure perfect fit. But I was wondering if there is a package or a known way to try to fit as close as possible to the ideal bins.

Comment: @FrankHarrell In order to try to match an existing set of bins out of interest, nothing fancy.

Comment: I'm confident that the existing set of bins is arbitrary.  It's not always a good idea to match non-ideal situations.

Comment: @FrankHarrell It is very possible that's true, but as odd as it might seem the purpose here isn't to create the best possible model, it's to match an existing one.

Comment: What was the purpose and method of binning for the existing model?

Comment: @FrankHarrell That's the thing, unfortunately I don't know how the bins were created, just what the probabilities are for each bin.

Comment: Just be extremely skeptical about it.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Alternatively, how could I take the raw log odds output and try to find groups that match a certain probability without binning by any particular independent variable? Would that be better?

Comment: You haven't stated the goal in doing this, which I'd need to know in order to answer.  But at first blush you wouldn't do that on the log odds scale.  You'll find that what you mean by 'match' is quite arbitrary on any scale.

Comment: I agree with @FrankHarrell.  Without knowing the purpose for binning, it will be nearly impossible to give you a sensible answer.  What often times happens is that bins of probabilities are formed by taking deciles of the predicted probabilities and then calculating the mean or median within each of the deciles so that they describe the "average" value in the bin.

Comment: And for that purpose it is far, far better to construct a smooth calibration curve that uses no binning.  The mean squared error of estimates will be significantly lower than any binning method.  Note you would always take the mean of a predicted probability, not the median.